# Android Studio HAXM Installer Errors

Tags: android

Im New to Android Studio Guys and following a tutorial in YouTube for developing Android Apps. I Have Installed the Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM Installer) but when launching the AVD It Says the HAXM is not installed... For the matter im using a AMD Processor.t the end i am getting same error ..

Comment: Please Read Nice Paper

https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration

Answer (score 0):

well, [HAXM](https://github.com/intel/haxm) is Intel's product, so isn't supporting AMDs processors... (this isn't just some software, it needs hardware support)

check out on AMDs site that your proc is supporting [AMD Virtualization (AMD-V, SVM) extensions](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration.html#extensions). if not then (from linked doc):

> If your processor doesn't support one of these extensions, then you can't use VM acceleration.

and your life become hell as Android emulators without virtualisation are VERY slowny